# How to get the first column data in sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to get the first column like below sql but my code show error.

```
SELECT subject FROM setting WHERE rowid=1

    public void getSetting(){
    result = "";

SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();   

Cursor c = db.query(true, "setting", new String[] {"subject", "language", "selection"}, "row=1", null, null, null, null, null);

    for(c.moveToFirst();!(c.isAfterLast());c.moveToNext()){

result = result + c.getString(0);
result = result + c.getString(0);
    result = result + c.getString(0);
    }
    if (c.getCount() == 0)              
    result = result + "result not found";   

c.close();      
db.close();         
myDbHelper.close(); 

}
```

Comment: and what error you are getting ? please upload error log in question

Comment: Your query is SELECT subject FROM setting WHERE rowid=1 whereas your where statement in cursor is row=1 is this just a typo?

Comment: Also `for(c.moveToFirst();!(c.isAfterLast());c.moveToNext())` can be `while(c.moveToNext())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stuff is a little hard to understand, but i think i have an idea what you want. You what to get a cursor to return only one row where the row's id is a specific value. And you only want the string from one column of that returned row. I assume that the primary issue is your designation of the `_id` column that you're looking for. You either called it `row` or `rowid`, you gotta double-check that.

Moreover, i hope the following re-write clears up further issues that you might have.

```
public String getSetting() {
    String result = "";
    String[] columns = {"subject"}; 
    String[] selectionArgs = {"1"};
    String LIMIT = String.valueOf(1); // <-- number of results we want/expect

    SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();   
    Cursor c = db.query(true, "setting", columns, "rowid = ?", selectionArgs, null, null, null, LIMIT);     

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        result = result + c.getString(0);
    } else {
        result = result + "result not found";
    }

    c.close();      
    myDbHelper.close();
    return result;
}
```

Moreover, moreover. If you get an error you should post it so that we have an idea what's going on.